# Append multiple lines in multiple files

Tags: python, append, multiline

I need to create a certain number of files that always have the same lines inside them.

With this script, I can create the "schede" folder in which a certain number of *.tex files are created.

Latex strings are written only in the last tab, while the others remain blank. How can I have all the forms filled in?

[image]

```
import os
import subprocess
work_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
if not os.path.exists("schede"):
    os.mkdir("schede")
os.chdir(os.path.expanduser(work_path+"/schede"))
n = 5   #put the number as you wish

for i in range(n):
    file_name = "S"+str(i).zfill(1)+".tex"
    subprocess.call(['touch', file_name]) #crea 34 file s.tex

def append_new_line(file_name, text_to_append):
    """Append given text as a new line at the end of file"""
    # Open the file in append & read mode ('a+')
    with open(file_name, "a+") as file_object:
        # Move read cursor to the start of file.
        file_object.seek(0)
        # If file is not empty then append '\n'
        data = file_object.read(100)
        if len(data) > 0:
            file_object.write("\n")
        # Append text at the end of file
        file_object.write(text_to_append)
        
def append_multiple_lines(file_name, lines_to_append):
    # Open the file in append & read mode ('a+')
    with open(file_name, "a+") as file_object:
        appendEOL = False
        # Move read cursor to the start of file.
        file_object.seek(0)
        # Check if file is not empty
        data = file_object.read(100)
        if len(data) > 0:
            appendEOL = True
        # Iterate over each string in the list
        for line in lines_to_append:
            # If file is not empty then append '\n' before first line for
            # other lines always append '\n' before appending line
            if appendEOL == True:
                file_object.write("\n")
            else:
                appendEOL = True
            # Append element at the end of file
            file_object.write(line)

def main():
    append_new_line(file_name, 'This is second line')
    print('Append multiple lines to a file in Python')
    list_of_lines = [
        '\ecvtitle{}{}',
    '\ecvitem{\ecvhighlight{Organizzato da:}}{\\textbf{}}',
       '\ecvitem{\ecvhighlight{}}{}',
        '\ecvitem{}{}',
    '\ecvitem{\ecvhighlight{Programma Formativo:}}{}',
    '\smallskip',
      '\ecvitem{}{',
          '\\begin{ecvitemize}'
            '\item  scrivere un\'item',
         '\\end{ecvitemize}',
         '}']
    # Append strings in list as seperate new lines in the end of file
    append_multiple_lines(file_name, list_of_lines)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: `file_name` is a *single* variable containing *one* string. You overwrite but the last name.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thank you for the suggestion. I am not very familiar with python, I have just started and I do not understand well how to set this you suggest

Answer (score 0):

As [@MisterMiyagi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5349916/mistermiyagi) said file_name is one variable so every time you make a file it is overwritten

I suggest making a list called files = []
and instead of just `file_name = "S"+str(i).zfill(1)+".tex"`

add `files.append(file_name)`
to the end of the for loop where you create the files.

and change the main to do the instructions for each file.

```
def main():
    for file_name in file:
        append_new_line(file_name, 'This is second line')
        print('Append multiple lines to a file in Python')
        list_of_lines = [
        '\ecvtitle{}{}',
        '\ecvitem{\ecvhighlight{Organizzato da:}}{\\textbf{}}',
        '\ecvitem{\ecvhighlight{}}{}',
        '\ecvitem{}{}',
        '\ecvitem{\ecvhighlight{Programma Formativo:}}{}',
        '\smallskip',
        '\ecvitem{}{',
        '\\begin{ecvitemize}'
        '\item  scrivere un\'item',
        '\\end{ecvitemize}',
        '}']
        # Append strings in list as seperate new lines in the end of file
        append_multiple_lines(file_name, list_of_lines)
```